# Most efficient way of doing static HTML in multiple languages

Tags: localization, gruntjs, mustache, template-engine

So I would need to make static HTML pages in multiple languages and now I'm looking what way it would best to do. HTML of the pages stays same, as does images. Basically only text content changes from localisation to another. Page structure is something like this:

```
en/
../index.html (main/home page)
../catalogue.html
../video.html
../examples.html
de/
../index.html (main/home page)
../catalogue.html
../video.html
../examples.html
```

So layout (html, css and images) are same on all pages. Just text content changes. There are about 10 different languages. What tool would you use for the injecting text (from json file?) to each template and automatically building needed folders & files. Grunt + mustache?

This is pretty simple so I don't really want to use any CMS for this. For sass etc I will use Grunt already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going the grunt way here are some thoughts:

Take a look at [grunt-dom-munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger), it's designed to manipulate html's using standard selectors. You can replace text, elements, append new ones or remove existing, whatever you need.

If you also need to copy files from here to there after transforming them you may want to use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy).

Moreover, do not forget that the *Gruntfile* is plain javascript so you can write your own custom functions to do whatever manipulations or operations you may need.

Hope this helps you get started...

Comment: Thanks. Will take loot at these! :)